# How can a JLabel containing only text be aligned within a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel

Normally, I would just create the `JLabel` using a string as the first parameter and `JLabel.CENTER` as the second parameter; adding the label to the panel using `BorderLayout.CENTER` would then cause the text in the label to be aligned in the center of the panel.

However, I'm using the 'RichJLabel' class in order to get a drop shadow on my text. To do this, it overrides `Component.paintComponent` in such a way that the alignment information is lost, and the label's text is drawn in the top left of the panel no matter what I do.

From what I understand, the workaround for this is to encase the label inside of another panel; that way, I can align the panel itself inside the parent panel, but I'm uncertain of how exactly to do this.

My complete goal is to:

- Figure out what font size a given string needs in order to fill up its parent JPanel
- Add a drop shadow to that text
- Center the text within its JPanel

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class RichJLabel extends JLabel {

    private int tracking;

    public RichJLabel(String text, int tracking) {
        super(text, JLabel.CENTER);
        this.tracking = tracking;
    }

    private int left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y;
    private Color left_color, right_color;

    public void setLeftShadow(int x, int y, Color color) {
        left_x = x;
        left_y = y;
        left_color = color;
    }

    public void setRightShadow(int x, int y, Color color) {
        right_x = x;
        right_y = y;
        right_color = color;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         String text = getText();
         FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(getFont());

         int w = fm.stringWidth(text);
         w += (text.length()-1)*tracking;
         w += left_x + right_x;
         int h = fm.getHeight();
         h += left_y + right_y;

         return new Dimension(w,h); 
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        char[] chars = getText().toCharArray();

        FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(getFont());

        int h = fm.getAscent();
        int x = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            char ch = chars[i];
            int w = fm.charWidth(ch) + tracking;

            g.setColor(left_color);
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x-left_x,h-left_y);

            g.setColor(right_color);
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x+right_x,h+right_y);

            g.setColor(getForeground());
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x,h);

            x+=w;
    }

        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_DEFAULT);

    } // end paintComponent()

public static void main(String[] args) {

  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
  panel1.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
  panel1.setBorder( BorderFactory.createBevelBorder( BevelBorder.LOWERED ));

  JPanel interiorPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
  panel1.add(interiorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  RichJLabel label = new RichJLabel("100", 0);
  label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
  label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
  label.setVisible( true );
  label.setForeground( Color.YELLOW );

  interiorPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 140));
  label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(140f));


  //resize code
  Font labelFont = label.getFont();
  String labelText = label.getText();
  int stringWidth = label.getFontMetrics(labelFont).stringWidth(labelText);
  int componentWidth = interiorPanel.getWidth();

  // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
  double widthRatio = (double)componentWidth / (double)stringWidth;
  int newFontSize = (int)(labelFont.getSize() * widthRatio);
  int componentHeight = interiorPanel.getHeight();

  // Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
  int fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, componentHeight);
  // Set the label's font size to the newly determined size.
  label.setFont(new Font(labelFont.getName(), Font.BOLD, fontSizeToUse));
  label.setLeftShadow(-3,-3,Color.BLACK);     

  // drop shadow w/ highlight
  label.setRightShadow(2,3,Color.black);
  label.setForeground(Color.gray);

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label SSCCEE");
  frame.getContentPane().add(panel1);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

What it does right now is this:

[image: gray box inside blue panel]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Alright, it should compile now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code was checking for the size of the container too soon.  Before it is displayed, it has a width/height of 0.

[image: Text with shadow]

### Altered code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class RichJLabel extends JLabel {

    private int tracking;

    public RichJLabel(String text, int tracking) {
        super(text, JLabel.CENTER);
        this.tracking = tracking;
    }

    private int left_x, left_y, right_x, right_y;
    private Color left_color, right_color;

    public void setLeftShadow(int x, int y, Color color) {
        left_x = x;
        left_y = y;
        left_color = color;
    }

    public void setRightShadow(int x, int y, Color color) {
        right_x = x;
        right_y = y;
        right_color = color;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
         String text = getText();
         FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(getFont());

         int w = fm.stringWidth(text);
         w += (text.length()-1)*tracking;
         w += left_x + right_x;
         int h = fm.getHeight();
         h += left_y + right_y;

         return new Dimension(w,h);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        char[] chars = getText().toCharArray();

        FontMetrics fm = this.getFontMetrics(getFont());

        int h = fm.getAscent();
        int x = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<chars.length; i++) {
            char ch = chars[i];
            int w = fm.charWidth(ch) + tracking;

            g.setColor(left_color);
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x-left_x,h-left_y);

            g.setColor(right_color);
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x+right_x,h+right_y);

            g.setColor(getForeground());
            g.drawString(""+chars[i],x,h);

            x+=w;
    }

        ((Graphics2D)g).setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_DEFAULT);

    } // end paintComponent()

public static void main(String[] args) {

  JPanel panel1 = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
  panel1.setBackground( Color.BLUE );
  panel1.setBorder( BorderFactory.createBevelBorder( BevelBorder.LOWERED ));

  JPanel interiorPanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
  panel1.add(interiorPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  RichJLabel label = new RichJLabel("100", 0);
  label.setLeftShadow(-3,-3,Color.BLACK);

  // drop shadow w/ highlight
  label.setRightShadow(2,3,Color.black);

  label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
  label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
  label.setVisible( true );
  label.setForeground( Color.YELLOW );

  interiorPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 140));
  label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(140f));

  //resize code
  Font labelFont = label.getFont();

  JFrame frame = new JFrame("Label SSCCEE");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setContentPane(panel1);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);

  int componentWidth = interiorPanel.getWidth();
  String labelText = label.getText();
  int stringWidth = label.getFontMetrics(labelFont).stringWidth(labelText);
  // Find out how much the font can grow in width.
  double widthRatio = (double)componentWidth / (double)stringWidth;
  int newFontSize = (int)(labelFont.getSize() * widthRatio);
  int componentHeight = interiorPanel.getHeight();

  // Pick a new font size so it will not be larger than the height of label.
  int fontSizeToUse = Math.min(newFontSize, componentHeight);
  System.out.println("fontSizeToUse: " + fontSizeToUse);
  if (fontSizeToUse<1) {
      System.err.println("Font size less than 1!");
      System.exit(1);
  }

  // Set the label's font size to the newly determined size.
  label.setFont(new Font(labelFont.getName(), Font.BOLD, fontSizeToUse));
  label.setForeground(Color.gray);
 }
}
```

Comment: This code works great on its own, but when I tried to add it to my code (the context is, there are a bunch of these objects that inherit from JPanel that are cells inside a JPanel with a GridLayout), the same alignment problem arose, even though I was using an extra interior panel to set the text's alignment.

Comment: I made a few extensions (honoring center alignment, for one): http://tinybrain.de/1011147

Answer (score 1):

If it is this [RichJLabel](http://code.google.com/p/filthy-rich-clients/source/browse/trunk/swing-hacks-examples-20060109/Ch01-JComponents/02/RichJLabel.java?r=7), then take a look at `paintComponent`. I would sugges making your own shadowed label, maybe consisting out of two shadow labels and one foreground label. I did not expect to see a 3 times drawing of every character. Problematic: inefficient and cannot do scripting languages like arabic or combining diacritic characters (one char letter, another accent).

At some points hacking around isn't worth it. If you had seen the sources, who knows.

*I am not sure that I have the right code. It certainly might be of a very early version.*

---

RichJLabel has a `getPreferredSize()` suitable for layouting. `JPanel.setBounds(int, int, int, int)` is the single method by which resizing is done. Hence you can use absolute layouting in a JPanel (null layout).

```
public class EPanel2 extends JPanel {

    private RichJLabel label = new RichJLabel("", 0);
    public EPanel2(String text) {
        super(null);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN.brighter().brighter());

        label.setFont(new Font("Univers", Font.BOLD, 48));
        label.setText(text);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        label.setLeftShadow(2, 2, Color.RED);
        label.setRightShadow(2, 2, Color.ORANGE);
        label.setVisible(true);
        add(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        Dimension labelSize = label.getPreferredSize();
        int labelX = (width - labelSize.width) / 2;
        int labelY = (height - labelSize.height) / 2;
        label.setBounds(labelX, labelY, labelSize.width, labelSize.height);
    }

}
```

Comment: That is the same RichJLabel, and I did look at paintComponent. The thing is, I can't figure out how to get it to consider the alignment parameter. I don't know how it gets used in Java to begin with. I agree that it's not the best way to implement this, but the scope of the project is only a few days, and I don't need it to work with anything except English characters.

Comment: Can understand that, so coded an answer, still needing some work.